# Adding unique: true for add_column and add_index in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Even though my application isn't gonna allow a user to key in a location, I wanted to enforce a uniqueness on city in the database. Since my Rails app will be searching on the city column, I would like to add an index on the city column as well but was wondering if it matters adding unique: true on the index as well. Is this repetitive? If this doesn't make sense, I would really appreciate it if you could explain why.

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :city, unique: true
      t.string :state

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :locations, :city, unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know the `unique` option in the `create_table` block is actually not supported and doesn't do anything, see [TableDefinition](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column). To create the unique index, you need to call the method `add_index` the way you do now. Note that a unique index is both for uniqueness and for searching etc., there's no need to add two indexes on the same column.

Answer (score 36):

Using Rails 4, you can provide: index param a hash argument

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :city, index: {unique: true}
      t.string :state

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this only works with `create_table`, not with `add_column`.
When you use `add_column` and want to add an index, too, you will have to use `add_index` separately. See the last comment by arthurnn here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20616#issuecomment-144870870

Answer (score 5):

Add: `index: { unique: true }`

Example:

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, null: false, index: { unique: true }
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: `add_column` does not support the `index` option. https://makandracards.com/makandra/32353-psa-index-true-in-rails-migrations-does-not-work-as-you-d-expect

Answer (score 4):

You can specify unique index while scaffolding:

```
rails generate model Locations city:string:uniq state:string
```

This will create Model, Spec, Factory and this migration:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :city
      t.string :state

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :locations, :city, unique: true
  end
end
```

Rails knows what it's doing - nothing more is required.